# Assisted conversions report - last click or direct conversions not equal to campaign conversions

Tags: google-analytics

For one particular campaign, the "Last Click or Direct Conversions" total doesn't equal to the same number of conversions reported in the campaign report for the same period.

E.g. the campaign report shows 15 conversions whereas the assisted conversions report shows only 11 "Last Click or Direct Conversion".

Any idea why the numbers are different?